# On pressed button block the other buttons

Tags: android

How could I make my button to do the on click action even if the button is pressed and the finger is still on the screen (the button is not released). Or I would accept the solution that when a button is pressed and is not release, the other buttons on the layout to not be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `OnClickListener` consider using an `OnTouchListener`.  You can then detect when the user's finger touches:`ACTION_DOWN` and releases `ACTION_UP` the button.

A method like this would probably work fine:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {

        switch(event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //DISABLE THE OTHER BUTTONS
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // RE-ENABLE THE OTHER BUTTONS
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the onmousedown event rather than the onclick event in your javascript:

```
myButton.onmousedown = myOnClickFunction;
```